# Finding the set of n-bit integers related to a given integer by single bit 'hopping'

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Given an n-bit integer, I want to find the set of n-bit integers which are related to my original integer by the interchange of a single 1 by a single 0 where the interchanged 1 and 0 must be adjacent

So what I want is to find some function such that for example, if I gave it the binary `1011` (11 in base 10) it returns `0111` and `1101` (7 and 13 in base 10) 
ie. so this would look like:

```
>>> bit_hop(11, n=4)
[7, 13]
```

It's important that this function knows how many bits the number is because my other constraint is that I need this to have periodic boundary conditions such that for example `0111` would return not only `1011` but also `1110`, ie. the edges of the binary number should be adjacent.

Also, as said, only one swapping should be allowed per hop. This means that `bit_hop(1010)` should return `[1100, 0011, 1001, 0110]`

Does anyone have any ideas on how one might go about doing this? I know that this should involve some clever usage of the `>>`, `<<` and `^` operations but I'm having trouble seeing the synthesis.

Comment: Why not `1110`? Do the 1 and 0 have to be adjacent?

Comment: You can locate adjacent 1s and 0s by XORing your number with a 1-bit bitwise rotation of your number, and swap an adjacent 1 and 0 by XORing those bits with 11 (appropriately aligned).

Comment: Hm, this works when there are only two possible outputs ie. like with `1011` but it doesn't and can't work with `1010` which should give `[1100, 0011, 1001, 0110]`

Comment: Sounds like you're not going through all detections.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by detections. Perhaps I misunderstood your previous comment but the only two possible variations I see of your algorithm are `(n^rotate_right(n,4))^n` and `(n^rotate_left(n,4))^n`. Both of these for `n=1010` give `0101` which is not a valid output.

Comment: Yup, you misunderstood. The 1 bits of `n^rotate_right(n,4)` (or `n^rotate_left(n,4)`, either works) tell you where 1s and 0s were adjacent in the original number. XORing that with `n` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hm, I see. It was a coincidence that my nonsense worked `1011`.

Comment: Alright, it seems that I've figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this directly in binary, you have to notice a couple of things about the algorithm. First it always deals with adjacent bits, except for looping around from the first bit to the last. Second those bits must be different, if they're the same swapping them wouldn't do anything.

This code walks a 2-bit mask around the value and tests to see if the bits are different, then uses exclusive-or to swap them.

```
def bit_hop(x, n):
    for i in range(n-1):
        mask = 3 << i
        if x & mask != 0 and x & mask != mask:
            yield x ^ mask
    mask = (1 << (n-1)) | 1
    if x & mask != 0 and x & mask != mask:
        yield x ^ mask
```

Comment: Yep, this is a very nice, elegant solution!